# ListView with the reverse direction

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I build ListView that starts at the bottom and user has to scroll up and when it almost up, then it will fetch some data and append behind the first item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no native functionality for this. We have been using [react-native-invertible-scroll-view](https://github.com/exponentjs/react-native-invertible-scroll-view) and it's been working great.

https://github.com/exponentjs/react-native-invertible-scroll-view

Comment: Oh, really, I didn't see this module. Thank you, I'll try that.